# Going to Bangladesh

Tags: bangladesh, south-asia

My friend and I are considering going to Bangladesh in early January 2013.
We were wondering if anyone here has been there and has some good or bad things they could tell us.

The country is very overpopulated, so if you go to the country sides, will you be able to go somewhere where you might be alone, and if so, would it be safe to travel the country using public transportation ?

Our idea is to travel around, and especially enjoy what nature the country have to offer.
It is very hard finding anyone who has been there.

Comment: Hello Mogens Elmer, welcome to Travel.SE. Unfortunately, your question is too vague in this form as you didn't mention what exactly you would like to know about the country. Is it prices, places to visit, availability of accommodation or something else? This site is made so that travelers could get answers to exact and specific questions or problems. Please revise the question or else it will be closed as `not a real question`.

Comment: Hi Mogens. I'd like to add to what @rlesko mentioned. Please understand that Travel.SE is different from general travel forums. It's meant for *specific* questions that have an objective answer. Your question as it is now is asking for opinions, and not suitable for Travel.SE. But please do ask specific questions related to your planned travel!

Comment: @rlesko I think Bangladesh is south Asian country not a southeast Asian country. right?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought everything east of India was southeast Asia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been there many times (around 15 times), most of the times I spent 1 or 2 days (crew member layover). I only stayed in Dhaka (the capital). Last visit was 5 years ago and once my seniority in the company was better I stopped going there. I do not have much to say but I will try to sort the things I have experienced there which unfortunately are negative in general:

- Not safe at night. I was about to be beaten at night in attempt to steal me.
- I had food poisoning twice, and that was from the hotel food! and that was a 5 stars hotel. I do not want to imagine what kind of problems would I get from street food.
- Hotel water was yellowish...
- Traffic was an issue, people drive badly. I almost had an accident while in *Riksha* (Rickshaw).
- Strikes are so common there. I had an extended layover there (4 days) because of a major strike. My Embassy sent us a warning not to go out during that. In total I experienced 3 strikes there!
- There are many beggars almost anywhere you go, if you give one, the rest will come to you. They will follow you even after you are inside your car. That's a nightmare for me.
- Streets are super dirty...
- Do not go in the rain seasons. Floods are common there and they are dangerous.

Anyway, the prices are cheap there, you can do a lot with little money. Try to go to Bango Bazar which is a local market that sells clothes for well known brands at very cheap prices like 4 or 5 USD for the piece. They have factories there for the major clothing brands and the rejected or defected clothes are sent there (minor defects that can not be seen by the eye). There are some *modern* malls there.

I'm sorry I have said a lot of negative things but that's out of my personal experience and I haven't been to the countryside of Bangladesh so I hope things are better there.

Comment: Hello, I am from Bangladesh. Our country is not that bad. Next time if you visit Bangladesh, try to go to the other cities / countryside, you can enjoy a beauty that will make your day, and our people are very hospitable, if you travel to more areas, you can see yourself. Next time visiting my country, mail me. I will try to make your experience in Bangladesh better.